# Raphael JS Question

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am following a tutorial from netuts about raphael js and I dont understand one of the examples, could some one possibly explain this to me in plainer english. I know I should learn more about javascript first.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i+=1) {
     var multiplier = i*5;
     paper.circle(250 + (2*multiplier), 100 + multiplier, 50 - multiplier); }
```

Thanks! Very Much

Comment: 4 spaces before a line formats as code. `ctr-k` to do it with a selection.

Comment: Note that's it's more common to write `++i` or `i++`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code will create five circles

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i+=1) { // loop five times => create five circles
    var multiplier = i*5;     // multiply i to increase the effect in the next lines
    paper.circle( 250 + (2*multiplier), // the x coordinate of the new circle
                  100 + multiplier, // the y coordinate
                  50 - multiplier); // the radius
}
```

Results in this SVG element:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="556" height="109">
<desc>Created with Raphaël</desc>
<defs/>
    <circle cx="250" cy="100" r="50" fill="none" stroke="#000"/>
    <circle cx="260" cy="105" r="45" fill="none" stroke="#000"/>
    <circle cx="270" cy="110" r="40" fill="none" stroke="#000"/>
    <circle cx="280" cy="115" r="35" fill="none" stroke="#000"/>
    <circle cx="290" cy="120" r="30" fill="none" stroke="#000"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: do you start counting at 0 for the loops. so it goes 0,1,2,3,4 which equals 5 circles?

Comment: Yes, you can see that in the first line. The loop variable i is set to 0 and will be incremented by one as long as it is smaller than 5, so the loop body will be executed with i=0, i=1, i=2, i=3, and i=4. Also see [For-Loop article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop)

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i+=1) {
```

Iterate 5 times. Store the number of times iterated so far in the variable i. The "{" begins the loop.

```
var multiplier = i * 5;
```

Multiply i by 5 and store in a variable called multiplier.

```
paper.circle(250 + (2*multiplier), 100 + multiplier, 50 - multiplier);
```

Draw a circle with an x coordinate at 250 plus twice the multiplier, a y coordinate at 100 plus the multiplier and with a radius of 50 minus the multiplier. (Essentially a fancy way of getting distinct circles.)

```
}
```

End the loop.